# How do I interpretably identify mixture distributions?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, inference, mixture-distribution

I am trying to measure the impact of a binary variable $B$ on continuous $y$, with some covariates $X$. I fit an OLS regression and a mixture model of $2$ OLS regressions. The mixture model fits much better and indicates that in one component the effect of $B$ is close to $0$ while in the other it is very positive.

The models are

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1B + \beta_2X + \epsilon$$

either as one OLS regression or a mixture-of-regressions model with $2$ components.

How can I identify what is it about the second component that makes $B$ work?

Comment: It depends on the specific models you are fitting.  In particular, did you or did you not include the appropriate interaction in your single model?

Comment: No, I don't have any interactions in the models.